# A local or parameter named 'nextjunction' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local

Tags: c#

I am creating a game in windows forms application. The games basic premise is the user controls a car around a 2-dimensional birds eye view map. I have created a class called `junction` which indicates where 2 or more roads meet, the user can turn the vehicle at a junction based on available options. When the car reaches a junction, the next junction the car is guaranteed to meet is calculated through the code below. However, I am getting an error which doesn't allow me to reassign the calculated junction to the variable `nextjunction`.

> A local or parameter named 'nextjunction' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local

```
// nextjunction.north is a class attribute of "junction" stored as a Boolean
// which determines if there is potential for the car to move north or not.
// Same goes for other directions.

// nextjunction.northjunc is a class attribute of "junction" stored as a
// junction which indicates the first junction immediately north of the 
// given junction. Same goes for other directions, 
// eg. nextjunction.southjunc indicates the first junction immediately
// south of nextjunction.

if (nextusermove == "north" && nextjunction.north==true)
{
    junction nextjunction = nextjunction.northjunc;
}
else if (nextusermove == "east" && nextjunction.east == true)
{
    junction nextjunction = nextjunction.eastjunc;
}
else if (currentmove == "down" && nextjunction.south == true)
{
    junction nextjunction = nextjunction.southjunc;
}
else if (currentmove == "west" && nextjunction.west == true)
{
    junction nextjunction = nextjunction.westjunc;
}

//the error occurs on every line of nextjunction assignment
```

I would like `nextjunction` to get assigned correctly.

Comment: I think the way you have named your `attributes` (properties?) has caused you the headache. I get the feeling you are calling the 'current junction' and the 'next junction' both as 'next junction'. Maybe reconsider your naming. In your comments you say, _'north of the given junction'_ is the 'given' junction really the 'current junction'?

Comment: what is your junction class code?

Answer (score 0):

This is a circular reference and will not work...

```
junction nextjunction = nextjunction.northjunc;
```

`nextjunction` can not be instantiated and at the same time set its value from a property of itself.

I would consider renaming your properties, notice where I've renamed `nextjunction` to `currentjunction`. You didn't post all your code so I can't see how you are instantiating the `nextjunction`s that I've renamed to `currentjuction`, that said, try this...

```
junction nextjunction;
if (nextusermove == "north" && currentjunction.north == true)
{
    nextjunction = currentjunction.northjunc;
}
else if (nextusermove == "east" && currentjunction.east == true)
{
    nextjunction = currentjunction.eastjunc;
}
else if (currentmove == "down" && currentjunction.south == true)
{
    nextjunction = currentjunction.southjunc;
}
else if (currentmove == "west" && currentjunction.west == true)
{
    nextjunction = currentjunction.westjunc;
}
```